# Monoidal V-categories, and monoids

Tags: reference-request, monoidal-categories, enriched-category-theory

I am guessing that the definition of monoidal V-category is a V-category $\mathbf{A}$ together with a V-functor $(\boxtimes) \colon \mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{A} \to \mathbf{A}$ and a functor $i \colon \mathbf{I} \to \mathbf{A}$ from the [unit V-category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/unit+enriched+category), satisfying some conditions. Then a monoid $X \in \operatorname{ob}(\mathbf{A})$ would be given by a pair of maps $I \to \mathbf{A}(X \boxtimes X,X)$ and $I \to \mathbf{A}(i,X)$, satisfying some conditions. Or maybe, by two families of morphisms $\mathbf{A}(Y,X \boxtimes X) \to \mathbf{A}(Y,X)$ and $\mathbf{A}(Y,i) \to \mathbf{A}(Y,X)$ dinatural in $Y$, always satisfying some conditions.

I would like to stop guessing. Is this a good definition of monoid in this context? Are these studied anywhere that I can read and reference? I was trying to follow Kelly's "Basic concepts of enriched category theory", but I could not find anything there.

Comment: In "Centers and homotopy centers in enriched monoidal categories - Batanin, Markl" you can see a definition. They define also lax monoidal V-functors and one would imagine that a monoid is a lax monoidal V-functor from the unit V-category.

Comment: And, assuming your V is complete, you may define monoid homomorphisms as an equalizer.

Comment: I have found that Day's "On closed categories of functors" answers most of my questions at the beginning.